# Finding a string, in a string, with regex, regex_search

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string:

`string str = "C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/LeagueClientUx.exe" "--riotclient-auth-token=yvjM3_sRqdaFoETdKSt1bQ" "--riotclient-app-port=53201" "--no-rads" "--disable-self-update" "--region=EUW" "--locale=en_GB" "--remoting-auth-token=13bHJUl7M_u_CtoR7v8XeA" "--respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe" "--respawn-display-name=League of Legends" "--app-port=53230" "--install-directory=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends" "--app-name=LeagueClient" "--ux-name=LeagueClientUx" "--ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper" "--log-dir=LeagueClient Logs" "--crash-reporting=crashpad" "--crash-environment=EUW1" "--crash-pipe=\\.\pipe\crashpad_12076_CFZRMYHTBJGPBIUH" "--app-log-file-path=C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2020-07-13T13-33-41_12076_LeagueClient.log" "--app-pid=12076" "--output-base-dir=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends" "--no-proxy-server";`

I wanna grab the port number and remote auth token, and I do that with the following code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

string PrintMatch(std::string str, std::regex reg) {
    smatch matches;
    while (regex_search(str,matches,reg))
    {
        cout << matches.str(1) << endl;
        break;
    }

    return matches.str(1);

}


int main() {
    
    string str = "C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/LeagueClientUx.exe" "--riotclient-auth-token=yvjM3_sRqdaFoETdKSt1bQ" "--riotclient-app-port=53201" "--no-rads" "--disable-self-update" "--region=EUW" "--locale=en_GB" "--remoting-auth-token=13bHJUl7M_u_CtoR7v8XeA" "--respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe" "--respawn-display-name=League of Legends" "--app-port=53230" "--install-directory=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends" "--app-name=LeagueClient" "--ux-name=LeagueClientUx" "--ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper" "--log-dir=LeagueClient Logs" "--crash-reporting=crashpad" "--crash-environment=EUW1" "--crash-pipe=\\.\pipe\crashpad_12076_CFZRMYHTBJGPBIUH" "--app-log-file-path=C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2020-07-13T13-33-41_12076_LeagueClient.log" "--app-pid=12076" "--output-base-dir=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends" "--no-proxy-server";
    
regex reg("([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])");
    

        string port = PrintMatch(str, reg);

    
regex reg1("(remoting-auth-token=[^\d]*)");

    string output = PrintMatch(str, reg1);
        








}
```

´

Gives me the following output:

```
    53201
remoting-auth-token=13bHJUl7M_u_CtoR7v8XeA--respawn-comman
```

The amount of characters in port number(53201) doesn't change, so I get that sucessfully.
However the remoting-auth-token changes therefore I don't know how I can get it successfully also when changing length.

I wanna grab this part from the remoting auth token: "13bHJUl7M_u_CtoR7v8XeA", so I can store it in a variable for use in my APP, just like I've done with the port number.

Looking forward to hearing from you! :)

Comment: `regex reg1("remoting-auth-token=(\\w+)");`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/oFZq84).

Comment: Note that to get the port, you may use `regex reg("--riotclient-app-port=(\\d+)");`

Comment: Thanks, that is a step closer, giving me the auth-token with this one. However when the auth-token changes to "I6Dyxla-bYQsPdakyhnrRQ" it outputs the auth-token as "I6Dyxla"

:S

Comment: Correct. So what chars can it contain? How do you define the pattern for it? If there can be  letters, digits, `_` or `-`, you may use `regex reg1("remoting-auth-token=([\\w-]+)");`

Comment: I think it can contain those chars you named, however this might be wrong. I've tested a few times with a new token every time and this seems to get it, so thank you!

I should read up on regex so I probably can understand it better!

Comment: I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should study the syntax of your expected matches to extract them correctly.

To get the port number value, I'd use

```
regex reg("--riotclient-app-port=(\\d+)");
```

This way, you do not even need to care about the number of digits you match since it will capture a number after a known string.

If the auth token can only contain letters, digits, `_` or `-` you may use

```
regex reg1("remoting-auth-token=([\\w-]+)")
```

where `\w` matches a letter/digit/`_` and `-` matches a hyphen, `+` will match one or more occurrences.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/oFZq84).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to escape your str value. Every double-quotes (") character must be escaped with (\")

```
string str = "C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/LeagueClientUx.exe\" \"--riotclient-auth-token=yvjM3_sRqdaFoETdKSt1bQ\" \"--riotclient-app-port=53201\" \"--no-rads\" \"--disable-self-update\" \"--region=EUW\" \"--locale=en_GB\" \"--remoting-auth-token=13bHJUl7M_u_CtoR7v8XeA\" \"--respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe\" \"--respawn-display-name=League of Legends\" \"--app-port=53230\" \"--install-directory=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\" \"--app-name=LeagueClient\" \"--ux-name=LeagueClientUx\" \"--ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper\" \"--log-dir=LeagueClient Logs\" \"--crash-reporting=crashpad\" \"--crash-environment=EUW1\" \"--crash-pipe=\\.\pipe\crashpad_12076_CFZRMYHTBJGPBIUH\" \"--app-log-file-path=C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2020-07-13T13-33-41_12076_LeagueClient.log\" \"--app-pid=12076\" \"--output-base-dir=C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\" \"--no-proxy-server";
```

Second, use this pattern:

```
(?:--remoting-auth-token=)([^"]*)
```

You can access match group with index 1.

To test regexp you can use this link: https://regexr.com/58bpb

Comment: If OP escapes a double quote, that would be a different input though. Also, `(?:...)` non-capturing group is redundant in your pattern. `(?:a)` = `a`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I thought that `str` value would be read programmatically, so it probably will contain double-quotes and spaces. To avoid bugs after OP will try to use real input test data should be escaped.